# Where to go after _To Mock A Mockingbird_?

Tags: reference-request, combinatory-logic

So long ago I read Raymond Smullyan's delightful *To Mock A Mockingbird*, a gentle introduction to combinatory logic (representing combinators as 'birds' singing back and forth to each other).  I fell in love with the book and was fascinated by the subject, but most of the other information I've found has been much more dry (which isn't surprising) and seems geared primarily towards practical applications (which is, a little bit).

Is there a good next step that explores combinatory logic primarily from a foundational level, particularly one that explores some of the basis and representation issues that Smullyan's book covers?  It seems like the topic may to a certain extent be a 'dead subject' in that essentially all the information that could be wrung out of it already has been, but I'd still love to find another work that surveys the subject broadly but from a more technical perspective than Smullyan's book does.

Comment: This might not even be close to what you're looking for but http://dkeenan.com/Lambda/index.htm

Comment: @BumSkeeter That's not _quite_ what I'm after, but it's absolutely gorgeous!

Comment: I tried, and still am trying, to fully understand lambda, combinators, etc. It's like I know it, understand it, and have used it. But if I try to explain it even to myself in my head, its like dividing by zero.

Comment: If you're specifically looking for more Smullyan, there's [*Diagonalization and Self-Reference*](http://global.oup.com/academic/product/diagonalization-and-self-reference-9780198534501?cc=us&lang=en&tab=toc).

Comment: @Snowball I've got DSR, and I've got _Forever Undecided_ (which is a personal favorite and a fine first reference into modal logics), and _Recursion Theory for Metamathematics_ and _Set Theory and the Continuum Problem_ (which has one of the gentlest introductions to forcing that I've seen), so I'm pretty much full up on Smullyan. :-) I'm specifically curious about combinatorial logic.